# How BNO in Corda performs KYC?

Tags: blockchain, corda

How BNO is performing KYC process?What all things are collected or needed during KYC process?

Answer (score 0):

Each Corda network is different and is supposed to have its own governing policy which is agreed by the participants of the network. So the KYC process can also be different for different networks depending on the process they mutually agree upon.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Corda has specific roles that handle the issuance of certificates for [Joining an existing compatibility zone](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/joining-a-compatibility-zone.html). From the Corda documentation:

> To connect to a compatibility zone you need to register with its
> certificate signing authority (or doorman) by submitting a certificate
> signing request (CSR) to obtain a valid identity for the zone. This
> process is only necessary when the node connects to the network for
> the first time, or when the certificate expires. You could do this out
> of band, for instance via email or a web form, but there’s also a
> simple request/response utility built into the node.
>
> Before using this utility, you must first have received the trust
> store file containing the root certificate from the zone operator. For
> high security zones, this might be delivered physically.

The above process is anyway specific for each network, as the previous comment says.
You can also read about [Network Certificates](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/permissioning.html#certificate-hierarchy) to see what certificates are issued and managed and when.

Here below the difference between "Network" and "Compatibility Zone", from the [doc](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/compatibility-zones.html) :

> Every Corda node is part of a “zone” (also sometimes called a Corda
> network) that is permissioned. Production deployments require a secure
> certificate authority. We use the term “zone” to refer to a set of
> technically compatible nodes reachable over a TCP/IP network like the
> internet. The word “network” is used in Corda but can be ambiguous
> with the concept of a “business network”, which is usually more like a
> membership list or subset of nodes in a zone that have agreed to trade
> with each other.

Also, in the [Corda Network website](https://corda.network/participation/pre-joining/) you can find the document describing what to do to prepare in order to join it as a participant. It could be useful to get an idea of what are the roles and steps involved in joining the network.

Comment: So we assume that the node which wish to join a BN is already onboarded to CZ?

Comment: @Sil basically, yes. The term "network" can be confusing sometimes. I updated my answer with the meaning of CZ.